# Create a Zip, add empty subdirectory and add files to the new sub directory

Tags: php, zip

I cannot find a way to add files to the subdirectory. I have the following code. I am creating zip directory and added an empty directory. But I cannot find a way to add files to this new directory inside the zip

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){

    if($zip->addEmptyDir('Files')) {
        echo 'Created a new root directory';
        $zip->addFile('file1.txt');
    } else {
        echo 'Could not create the directory';
    }
    
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: To those who closed this, I am not able to get the answer to this question from the link provided.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#96382

Comment: @melvin that's what the example in the duplicate is doing - using the second parameter to specify the path within the zip. I agree it perhaps isn't immediately obvious though. It's the `$files['folder_path'].$files['fileName']` bit.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the update. It is really helpful. I didn't undesrtood the example. But now I get something